# Problem during the installation of Android Studio SDK Problem "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted"

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I install Android Studio for the first time.
I have this error :
SDK Problem
Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted.

I don't know how solve my problem.
Because I can't have a connection internet on this PC because it's a PC from my company.

I search online but the solution what I found need a connection internet.